# Replacing one of the conditions of a norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the definition of a norm on a real vector space X.
I want to show that replacing the condition

$\|x\| = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0\quad$
with
$\quad\|x\| = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$

does not alter the the concept of a norm (a norm under the "new axioms" will
fulfill the "old axioms" as well).

Any hints on how to get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to show is that $\|0\|=0$. Let $x$ be any element of the normed space. What is $\|0\cdot x\|$?

Comment: I am thinking that $\|0\cdot x\| = \|0\|\|x\|$, and so $\|0\|=\|0\|\|x\|$, how does this help? Could i get a few more hints? =)

Comment: Well, you need to distinguish the zero vector ${\bf 0}$ from plain old $0$ (the scalar).  The scalar product satisfies $||a\cdot {\bf x}||=|a| \cdot ||{\bf x}||$.  The zero vector satisfies $0 \cdot {\bf x}={\bf 0}$ for any ${\bf x}$ (and in particular ${\bf x}={\bf 0}$).  So $||{\bf 0}||=||0\cdot {\bf 0}||=|0| \cdot ||{\bf 0}|| = 0 \cdot ||{\bf 0}|| = 0$.